# Hamburger menu not working on iphone?

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

Hamburger menu does not open upon touch on iphone mobile devices, but works on android devices. Browers I'm using is chrome & safari iphone 4s device.

How can I get my website mobile friendly on iphone devices using hamburger menu?
here is the website: http://xavierbreaker.com/
Here is my code:

```
<div id="nav">
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">xyz company</a>
        <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="shows.html">Shows</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Media<i class=""></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="audiovisual.html">Audio/Visual</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Beats Coming Soon</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Safari, chrome...? All browsers on ios works the same? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and safari the iphone model is 4s

Comment: You have a JS error on Safari@iOS9. audioplayer.js - line 103 - IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value.

Comment: This --> `<a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></a>` should be `<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"></button>`; change the `a` tag to `button`. You're missing a doctype declaration also, see [Validator](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the site using Safari and Chrome on my iPhone 5s and the hamburger menu works fine. I am unable to test on an iPhone 4s but I hope the previous helps.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the input i fixed it couple of weeks ago but if you ever get chance to check on iphone 4s you can always update me thank you !!!!